# Determine if CSS property is set to a certain value?

Tags: jquery, attributes, hide, show

Just wondering how to determine a jQuery statement like this

```
if( $("#test").css('display', 'block') == true) {
   return true;
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to determine IF an element has is currently being shown or hidden via the "display:block" attribute ?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Use

```
if( $("#test").css('display') == 'block') {
```

I'm fairly sure `.css()`, returning a calculated value, will always return a lower case result - the docs say nothing on this. To make totally sure, you could do a

```
if( $("#test").css('display').toLowerCase() == 'block') {
```

while you can rely on `display` giving reliable results, note that some CSS properties **will not always show up the way they were defined**. For example

```
a { color: red }
```

will turn out `rgb(255,0,0);` when queried using `.css()`.

Comment: @Tom you are checking whether `test1` has `display: none` which it doesn't have. Do you mean `display != 'block'`?

Comment: @Pekka - Thanks for the response :) Nah, I wanted to check if #test is block - and if it is block then show test1 ?

Comment: @Tom yeah, I see now. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/eEF9Y/4/ you didn't  select jQuery in the menu to the left, the code works.

Answer (score 11):

You can use isvisible and is hidden also

```
if ( $('#test').is(':visible')){
```

Comment: This will actually work better if visibility is what you want to determine, +1

Comment: This is very interesting. I was trying to pause some videos that were hidden on mobile by a media query that applied display:none; to them, but consoling $(elm).css('display') returned 'block', which was their default value. Your answer did the trick with them. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to test this is by comparing with actual values:

```
function displayHidden(elem) {
    return $(elem).css('display') === 'hidden';
}
```