# how to add a css class for all elements that has particular style

Tags: javascript, jquery, styles

I wan to add a css class for all elements that has particular style.

Eg.  if there are 5 elements that with the style "**float:left**".

I want to remove the "**float:left**" and add "**align-left**" class.

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like below, but the target selector `*` is a bad one, so try to have better selector to target the desired elements

```
$('*').filter(function () {
    return this.style.float == 'left'
}).css('float', '').addClass('align-left')
```

Comment: @Alnitak thank :) ... I don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
if( $("#test").css('display') == 'block') {
  // Remove and add properties here
}
```

Thanks to Pekka in his answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928920/determine-if-css-attribute-is-a-certain-value)!